# Import or fetch contacts from gmail to 3rd party app or gadget

Tags: java, gmail, gdata

i want to import or fetch contacts from gmail into my application. I have done this by using **gdata** but my problem is that how can i get updated contact and new contacts everytime.

I have made a gadget which is adding in gmail. That gadget have two input fields that is `Contact name` and `Mobile number` and I want to retrieve contacts for that particular user who uses that gadget...

Is there any way to fetch contacts everytime in my gmail gadget if user login its gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add one more field for Gmail password and asks google server for the authorization and by received token you need to fetch contacts runtime so you client will have updated contact list every time. [you can do this by the same gdata API].